# Rails :Is this caching problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I'm new to rails, and have taken some existing site for new enhancements. I mirrored rails application from remote server, and running locally using "ruby script/server" server. 
The problem is any changes to the files are not being reflected in web browser. Is this because of caching somehwere. Can someone pls point me where should Ilook to disable this or come back to development env?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have copied the source from a production server, your application may not be in development mode, which means that the server will not automatically reload the files.

IIRC, you can set the application mode in `config/environment.rb`.

In development mode the files should be reloaded automatically, unless you are using require to load your classes.